# How do I show more digits of haskell's pi?

Tags: haskell, show, digits

I'd like to `take` more digits of the Prelude `pi` value.

```
Prelude> take 4 $ show pi
"3.14"
```

But

```
Prelude> take 17 $ show pi
"3.141592653589793"

Prelude> take 170 $ show pi
"3.141592653589793"
```

Is the `pi` constant just stored this truncated?  Is there an option in show to print to string more digits?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pi` is a method of the `Floating` class:

```
class Fractional a => Floating a where
  pi :: a
  ...
```

So `pi` is polymorphic, and it is up to the implementor of the instance to define it appropriately.

The most common instances are `Float` and `Double` which have limited precision:

```
Prelude> pi :: Float
3.1415927
Prelude> pi :: Double
3.141592653589793
```

but nothing is stopping you from using other packages, like `long-double` which gives a few more bits on some systems:

```
Numeric.LongDouble> pi :: LongDouble 
3.1415926535897932385
```

Or `rounded` which gives arbitrarily many bits of precision via the MPFR software implementation:

```
Numeric.Rounded> pi :: Rounded TowardNearest 100
3.1415926535897932384626433832793
Numeric.Rounded> pi :: Rounded TowardNearest 500
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081283
```

The `numbers` package provides a pure-Haskell implementation of constructive (exact) real numbers, which can be shown to as many digits as desired:

```
Data.Number.CReal> showCReal 100 pi
"3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068"
```

You can also have lower precision with the `half` package, maybe interoperable with GPU:

```
Numeric.Half> pi :: Half
3.140625
```

When you evaluate `pi` without giving a specific type, the interpreter's defaulting rules come into play.

> Each defaultable variable is replaced by the first type in the default list that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable’s classes. ... If no default declaration is given in a module then it assumed to be: `default (Integer, Double)` -- https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4

```
Prelude> :t pi
pi :: Floating a => a
```

`Integer` is not `Floating`, but `Double` is, so the ambiguous type gets resolved by defaulting to `Double`.  You can get more information by enabling `-Wtype-defaults`:

```
Prelude> :set -Wtype-defaults 
Prelude> pi

<interactive>:2:1: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Double’
        (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’ at <interactive>:2:1-2
        (Floating a0) arising from a use of ‘it’ at <interactive>:2:1-2
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
3.141592653589793
```

(Note: I wrote the `long-double` package and am the current maintainer of `rounded`.)

Comment: Would also be good to point out that `show pi` typechecks due to defaulting rules

Comment: NB: the `numbers` package was unmaintained for a few years, and the new maintainer isn't all that active (there are still open pull requests from 2014)

Comment: Sorry but I am having a little bit of difficulty accessing that `Data.Number.CReal`? I am using **Haskell GHC 8.10.3**. How do you import it since I am getting *"Could not find module `Data.Number.CReal`"*?

I figured you can install `numbers` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.2) package using `cabal install --lib numbers`, but still I cannot import.

Answer (score 0):

Pi defined as

```
 pi = 3.141592653589793238
```

So there is all digits you can have. Keep in mind that `Floating` typeclass is used to represent it.

Comment: Well, `pi` isn't really defined this way, it's only [the standard implementation in the `Double` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Float.html#line-521). Interestingly [also in `Float`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Float.html#line-376), although that can't even represent that many digits. But, as Claude says `pi` can have different implementations, including ones that can yield arbitrarily many digits.

Comment: Yes. You can have different `pi` for different type, but in this case we use this definition.